# CSS not working in IE8, while working fine in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

basically a majority of the CSS styles defined for my website are not displayed when opening the page in IE8. This is not only happening for my custom styles (which I load separately through a custom css file), but also for the built-in features of Rockettheme IONOSPHERE template, for example the `box1/2/3/4/5/6` module styles. Also, the rounded style is not rendered, and all modules are shown with sharp corners instead.

I am also using a custom css file (called `ralph_golfanatics.css`), which I load inside the index.php as follows:

```
$gantry->addStyles(array('template.css','joomla.css', 'ralph_golfanatics.css'));
```

All custom styles of this file are displayed fine in IE9, but the most important styles are not shown in IE8. Simply adding these css-styles manually in the file `template_ie8.css` (that file comes with the Ionosphere template package) did not change anything.

Looking forward to receive any help in this matter. The webpage is http://www.golfanatics.de

Thank you all in advance for your hints.

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the link you've included isn't working so it's difficult to pin down exactly what the problem is.

If you're referring to rounded borders displaying with sharp corners this is because `border-radius` is a CSS3 property which is not supported in IE8.

See [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) for border-radius browser support.

There are many CSS3 properties which don't work in older browsers; this is expected behavior and most web developers work around this by using either 'progressive enhancement' or 'graceful degradation'. See [this link](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) for more information.

Most websites using CSS3 techniques will *never* look the same in every browser.

Comment: In addition a good reference site is http://caniuse.com/, for checking what is and what is not going to work on which browser.